# Question on accrual percentages with contributions

Tags: percentages

Let's say I contribute a random amount per month to an account. I do this on the 1st of the month. For January through April, my contributions were $100.00, 120.00, 150.00,$ and $100.00$. On April 11th I check the account and find a balance of $500.00$. What is my percentage of interest expressed as APR? (I don't really care about the answer; I want to know how this is calculated.)

Side note - how do I type a dollar sign without messing up the entire page? :)

Comment: To type a dollar sign, without having it interpreted as beginning of MathJax, put a backslash ($\backslash$) in front of it.

Comment: Ahh, escape it. Got it. Thanks

Comment: Incidentally, this being a math site, we don't really _need_ dollar signs; it's essentially the same problem in any units of currency. (Though I doubt there would be any objection if you inserted them.)

Comment: Very true. And I hate to leave out a European answerer!